# Trying to print full line from a huge file that has \ (connector for lines)

Tags: shell, text-processing

I am trying to collect lines from a file with the specific word host:
for example the word host, I need to get output of all names of hosts. 
This is my file:

```
host= mx,rt,fd,rt,wed,asd, \
      fm, jklf,dfd,dfd
host = jd,er,ew,yu,tg,ed,ik,cs,\
       fd, gr, jy
host = mz,fg,jh
```

I am using :

$grep -i host filename  | awk '{print $2}'

only works for the first line , it does not output any name after \

so the output is;

```
   mx,rt,fd,rt,wed,asd, \

   jd,er,ew,yu,tg,ed,ik,cs,\

    mz,fg,jh
```

as you see I am not getting rest of the line after \

I don't want to get rid of   \  I would like to keep it, I can move it and connect all names, so it will be seen as one_line , but I don't want to do that.

Any idea , it is appreciated, it could be easy , but I can make it work, even when I use tr.

Comment: Show what your input is and what output you want. The fact that nobody responds is that you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give this a shot `awk '{gsub("host","");gsub("=","");print;}' filename`

`awk` remove the `host` and `=` and then just print each line.

Comment: It's standard awk (`awk '{print;}'`). Just try it.  I already did.

Comment: awk '{gsub("host","");gsub("=","");print;}' filename____


this Worked Thank you, it is very appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
 sed '
   # delete all but lines starting with host= (allowing blanks)
   /^[[:blank:]]*host[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/!d

   # remove that host= part
   s///
   :1
   /\\$/{
     # if the line ends in \, append the next line and loop 
     N;b1
   }'
```